# read a realtime database node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hi guys I would like as a title to read a single node created previously in my realtime firebase database, the database is thus created:

```
Users
   ---- UID1
          ---- Email:
          ---- Fullname:
          ---- Phone:
          ---- Coins:
   ---- UID2
          ---- Email:
          ---- Fullname:
          ---- Phone:
          ---- Coins:
```

so my database has a structure like the one shown and I need to read in onDataChange and then write the data in a TextView.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_coins_);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Utenti");
    myRef.child("Rapp Coins %").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String coinsRapp = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mCoins.setText(coinsRapp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

this method I used doesn't work as I can't get it to take the data I need.

I need to take the Coins value: within each different logged user, so each logged in user reads his data.

I the UID value that identifies each user, I created it based on his mobile number, so each user has his own mobile number that identifies him as UID.

this is all my code, as you can see the data that saves the UID is contained in mPhone, which was saved and then brought into this activity through the SharedPreferences.

```
public class PageCoins_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private AdView mBannerTop;
    private AdView mBannerBot;
    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
    public double Coins;
    double coinsOp = 0.00;
    double coinsCl = 0.00;
    double coinssum = 0.00;

    Button mButton;
    Button mPhonebtn;
    TextView mCoinscounter;
    TextView mCoins;
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    EditText mPhoneEdt;
    TextView mPhone;

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_coins_);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Utenti");
        myRef.child("Rapp Coins %").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String coinsRapp = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mCoins.setText(coinsRapp);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        initFirebase();

        //counter CRD
        mCoinscounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Textcoins);
        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        mPhoneEdt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumberPhEdt);
        mPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NumberPhTxt);
        mCoins = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtGen);
        mPhonebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPhone);

        //mPhoneEdt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //mPhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                }

                // Write a message to the database
                DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();
                myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("Rapp Coins Day %").setValue(mCoinscounter.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

        //Set Orientation Portrait
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        // Banner Top View Coins
        mBannerTop = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewTopcoins);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mBannerTop.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Banner Bot View Coins
        mBannerBot = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewBotcoins);
        AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mBannerBot.loadAd(adRequest1);

        getnumberprefs();

        //ADMob Video
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    private void getnumberprefs() {
        SharedPreferences numb = getSharedPreferences(Register_Activity.NUMB, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String numberphn = numb.getString(Register_Activity.KEY_NUMB,null);
        mPhone.setText(numberphn);
    }

    //boolean changepgcoins = true;

    public void changeNumber(View view) {

        /*if (changepgcoins == true){
            mPhoneEdt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mPhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            changepgcoins = false;
        }else{
            mPhoneEdt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changepgcoins = true;
        }*/

    }

    private void initFirebase() {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }

    public void HomeClick(View view){
        Intent intenthome = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intenthome);
    }

    public void displayCrd (double amount){
        mCoinscounter.setText(String.format("%.2f", amount));
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    public void logout(View view) {
        mAuth.signOut();
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        FirebaseUser currentuser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentuser == null){
            Intent intTologin = new Intent(this, Login_Activity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intTologin);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Video Caricato");

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " RAPp " + " COINS " + " : " + rewardItem.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Coins += rewardItem.getAmount();
        displayCrd(Coins/40200*100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Caricamento Fallito");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        if (!isEmpty(mCoins)){

            String coinsopen = mCoins.getText().toString();
            String coinscounter = mCoinscounter.getText().toString();

            coinsOp = Double.parseDouble(String.format(coinsopen.replace(',', '.'), "%.2f"));
            coinsCl = Double.parseDouble(String.format(coinscounter.replace(',', '.'), "%.2f"));

            coinssum = (coinsOp + coinsCl);

            mCoinscounter.setText(String.valueOf(coinssum));

            // Write a message to the database
            DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();
            myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("Rapp Coins %").setValue(mCoinscounter.getText().toString());


        }else{

            // Write a message to the database
            DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference();
            myRef.child("Utenti").child(mPhone.getText().toString()).child("Rapp Coins %").setValue(mCoinscounter.getText().toString());
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private boolean isEmpty(TextView mCoins) {
        String input = mCoins.getText().toString();
        return input.length() == 0.00;
    }

}
```

I really ask for help on the solution of this thing because it's the last thing I need to finish and I can't thank you.

```
{
      "Utenti" : {
        "3********4" : {
          "E-Mail" : "",
          "Full Name" : "",
          "Phone" : "",
          "Rapp Coins %" : "",
          "Rapp Coins Day %" : ""
        },
        "3********1" : {
          "E-Mail" : "",
          "Full Name" : "",
          "Phone" : "",
          "Rapp Coins %" : "",
          "Rapp Coins Day %" : ""
        },
       }
    }
```

this is my database so composed.

Comment: use this dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()

Comment: The code you show reads path `/Utenti/Rapp Coins %`, which doesn't exists in the data structure you showed. It'll be easier to help if the data and code match. I highly recommend adding the actual JSON to your question (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: call your get data to firebase after click on btn2  because you are add data in click button and get on onCreate method So, that time data was no exist because you not add data first you directly call for get data

Comment: on btn2 the data work because those would be the daily data that are added to the total data that I have to read on the database and precisely the "Rapp Coins%"

Comment: Please add a more detailed database schema so we can see it more clearly and please also responde with @